# AspectJ method not being called when calling delete method on JpaRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-aop

I have a manytomany relationship between an object called seedrecord and an object called affiliatelink. In order for the affiliatelink to be removed i need to first remove the reference to it from every seedrecord's affiliateList. After that i delete the object with the delete method of spring Jparepository. Because i have different delete methods in my service (AffiliateLinkService) i decided to put this piece of code in a AspectJ class. However when the deletemethod is called the aspectJ method isn't called before that. Could anyone look at my code and tell me whats wrong?

```
@Before("execution(* org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.delete(..))" +
        "&& within(Services.AffiliateLinkService) && args(entity)")
private void deleteAffiliateLinkFromSeedRecordAffiliateLists(Object entity){
    log.info("hailing from SystemListenerService!");
    ((AffiliateLink)entity).getSeedRecords()
            .forEach(seedRecord -> {
                seedRecord.getAffiliateLinks()
                        .remove(seedRecord);
                seedRecordDao.save(seedRecord);
            });
}
```

EDIT: The problem isn't caused by the jparepository method. Because when i change the delete method with wrapper method called deleteMe() and let the aspect method run before this wrapper method it doesn't work either..

```
@Before("execution(* Services.AffiliateLinkService.deleteMe(..))" +
        "&& args(entity)")
```

Also for your information, I have the aspect declared as bean and the config class declared with `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`

EDIT 2: Things get even weirder when i change @Before in `@Afterthrowing("execution(* *(..))")`.

Then suddenly i get this error during application startup.

> Description:
>
> The bean 'dataSourceInitializer' could not be injected as a
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer'
>   because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
>     org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
>
> Action:
>
> Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the
>   use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on
>   @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.

The problem is that i have nowhere a bean called `dataSourceInitializer` declared explicitly so i cant annotate it with @Enable this or that... God how i hate Spring.

PS: I have another method that is called after returning of the save method of jparepository and it works as a charm so i don't understand why the delete advice doesnt work. Here is the annotation of the working method.

@AfterReturning("execution(* org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.save(..))" +
           "&& !within(Services.SystemListenerService) && args(entity)")

EDIT 3: It has something to do with the argument AffiliateLink that i'm using. When i replace the AffiliateLink argument with a long for example, the before method is getting called… This is the Affiliatelink pojo. But i don't think there is anything unusual about the pojo that could cause this:

```
@Entity
public class AffiliateLink implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    @URL
    private String affiliateUrl;

    @URL
    private String affiliateImageUrl;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private Double productValue;

    private boolean general;

    private byte rank;

    private boolean linkBroken;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date creationDate;


    @ElementCollection @CollectionTable( name = "affiliate_keywords", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id") ) @Column(name="keyword")
    private Set<String> keywords;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "affiliateLinks")
    private Set<SeedRecord> seedRecords = new HashSet<>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private LocalizedStorefront localizedStorefront;

    private long seedId;

    private boolean plantClimbs;

    private boolean spicy;

    private boolean teaPlant;

    public AffiliateLink() { }

    public AffiliateLink(AffiliateLinkCreateDTO affiliateLinkCreateDTO) {
        this.title = affiliateLinkCreateDTO.getTitle();
        this.description = affiliateLinkCreateDTO.getDescription();
        this.general = affiliateLinkCreateDTO.isGeneral();
        this.rank = affiliateLinkCreateDTO.getRank();
        this.localizedStorefront = affiliateLinkCreateDTO.getLocalizedStorefront();
        this.productValue = affiliateLinkCreateDTO.getProductValue();
        this.keywords = affiliateLinkCreateDTO.getKeywords();
        this.seedId = affiliateLinkCreateDTO.getSeedId() != null ? affiliateLinkCreateDTO.getSeedId() : 0;
    }

    public AffiliateLink(String affiliateUrl,
                         String affiliateImageUrl,
                         String title,
                         String description,
                         Double productValue,
                         boolean general,
                         byte rank,
                         boolean linkBroken,
                         Set<String> keywords,
                         LocalizedStorefront localizedStorefront,
                         long seedId,
                         boolean plantClimbs,
                         boolean spicy,
                         boolean teaPlant) {
        this.affiliateUrl = affiliateUrl;
        this.affiliateImageUrl = affiliateImageUrl;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.productValue = productValue;
        this.general = general;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.linkBroken = linkBroken;
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.localizedStorefront = localizedStorefront;
        this.seedId = seedId;
        this.plantClimbs = plantClimbs;
        this.spicy = spicy;
        this.teaPlant = teaPlant;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public boolean isPlantClimbs() {
        return plantClimbs;
    }

    public void setPlantClimbs(boolean plantClimbs) {
        this.plantClimbs = plantClimbs;
    }

    public boolean isSpicy() {
        return spicy;
    }

    public void setSpicy(boolean spicy) {
        this.spicy = spicy;
    }

    public boolean isTeaPlant() {
        return teaPlant;
    }

    public void setTeaPlant(boolean teaPlant) {
        this.teaPlant = teaPlant;
    }

    public long getSeedId() {
        return seedId;
    }

    public void setSeedId(long seedId) {
        this.seedId = seedId;
    }

    public Double getProductValue() {
        return productValue;
    }

    public void setProductValue(Double productValue) {
        this.productValue = productValue;
    }

    public String getAffiliateImageUrl() {
        return affiliateImageUrl;
    }

    public boolean isLinkBroken() {
        return linkBroken;
    }

    public void setLinkBroken(boolean linkBroken) {
        this.linkBroken = linkBroken;
    }

    public void setAffiliateImageUrl(String affiliateImageUrl) {
        this.affiliateImageUrl = affiliateImageUrl;
    }

    public String getAffiliateUrl() {
        return affiliateUrl;
    }

    public void setAffiliateUrl(String affiliateUrl) {
        this.affiliateUrl = affiliateUrl;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Set<String> getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(Set<String> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean isGeneral() {
        return general;
    }

    public void setGeneral(boolean general) {
        this.general = general;
    }

    public byte getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(byte rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Set<SeedRecord> getSeedRecords() {
        return seedRecords;
    }

    public void setSeedRecords(Set<SeedRecord> seedRecords) {
        this.seedRecords = seedRecords;
    }

    public LocalizedStorefront getLocalizedStorefront() {
        return localizedStorefront;
    }

    public void setLocalizedStorefront(LocalizedStorefront localizedStorefront) {
        this.localizedStorefront = localizedStorefront;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        AffiliateLink that = (AffiliateLink) o;
        return general == that.general &&
                rank == that.rank &&
                Objects.equals(id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equals(affiliateUrl, that.affiliateUrl) &&
                Objects.equals(affiliateImageUrl, that.affiliateImageUrl) &&
                Objects.equals(title, that.title) &&
                Objects.equals(description, that.description) &&
                Objects.equals(productValue, that.productValue) &&
                localizedStorefront == that.localizedStorefront;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, affiliateUrl, affiliateImageUrl, title, description, productValue, general, rank, localizedStorefront);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i solved the problem with this post on the spring forum. http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/100146-aspect-advice-is-never-called

A method should be public not static and called externally(which means the method should be in another class). So i've moved the deleteMe method to another class and called it from there and now the @Before aspect works.